# How do you send keys to a specific window in tmux?

Tags: tmux

If I have a `tmux` session called "Test", and inside "Test" I have two windows "Test1" and "Test2", how do I send a command to "Test2"?

`tmux send-keys -t Test.Test2 "STUFF HERE"` won't work. That syntax is for panes only.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Unbelievable. I searched everywhere for an answer on the web and I could not find it. Apparently it is just:

`tmux send-keys -t Test:Test1 "TEST" C-m`

Comment: How would one accomplish this for a specific pane?

Comment: The syntax for a specific pane is `tmux send-keys -t {session}:{window}.{pane}`, so  `tmux send-keys -t Test:Test1.1 "TEST" C-m` would send that to the first pane.

Comment: You can also specify `tmux send-keys -t ':.!'` to mean "last active session (i.e. the current one), last active window, previously selected pane."

Comment: you can find out the target pane's *pane ID* by executing `echo $TMUX_PANE` inside the target pane. This will output e.g. `%1`. With information, you can *send  keys* from anywhere (not necessarily from within *tmux*) with e.g the following command: `tmux send-keys -t %1 "whoami" C-m`